# What does a twice differentiable function mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question

In many contexts, I have seen phrases like "... function $f$ is twice differentiable ...". I can understand that the function $f$ can be differentiated twice or in other words its second derivative exists. But does this mean third derivative (or higher) does not exist or is equal to $0$?

In the same way, what would we call a function like $e^x, \sin x, \dots$ which can be differentiated any number of times?

Comment: Take $x|x|$. This function is once differentiable with a continuous first derivative. But its first derivative is not differentiable at $0$. The same concept applies to higher order derivatIves

Comment: CGPT says: *A twice differentiable function is a function that can be differentiated twice and the result is also a function. Examples of twice differentiable functions include polynomials of degree at least 2 and most commonly encountered functions in calculus such as $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $e^x$, and $\ln x$.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twice differentiable functions can be thrice differentiable.

Functions like $e^{x}, \sin x $ are **infinitely differentiable** functions or $C^{\infty}$ functions..

Comment: If twice differentiable functions can be thrice differentiable, why do texts mention that they are only twice differentiable and not thrice, sir?

Comment: They are proving something assuming that the second derivative exist. There is no harm if more derivatives exist.

Comment: If you say that $x>1$ does it mean that $x$ cannot be greater than $2$? Of course it can be. It s the same story here.

Comment: With respect to your second comment, if the third derivative exists, it implies the second derivative exists. On the other hand, if $x>2$ it does not mean $x>1$. Could you please explain this contradiction here, sir?

Comment: If $x>2$ then $x>1$.

Comment: Sorry sir, a silly mistake. Could you please suggest a good book for further reading in calculus for a Class 12 student?

Comment: I think I am not the right person to recommend a book for class 12 students. The books I suggest may turn out to be too advanced. I hope someone else will  suggest a good book.